# Just switched to TensorFlow 2.1 and got some annoying warnings

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.x

**System information:**

- Laptop PC
- OS Platform and Distribution: Ubuntu Linux, 18.04, x64
- TensorFlow installed from: pip
- TensorFlow version: 2.1.0
- Python version: 3.6.9
- GPU model and memory: nVidia RTX2060 6GB
- CPU model: i7-9850H
- RAM: 16GB

I was working with TensorFlow 2.0 on CPU with another PC.

I installed (using the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu ) CUDA 10.1.

I started running an old script for a NN using ResNet50V2 on a dataset of 26998 training images and 1000 as validation with 2 classes.

The NET

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
keras_layer (KerasLayer)     (None, 1792)              4363712   
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 64)                114752    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 130       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,478,594
Trainable params: 114,882
Non-trainable params: 4,363,712
_________________________________________________________________
```

where keras_layer is the resnet got from tensorflow_hub.

As first issue, I got a `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` that I solved adding

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for dev in physical_devices:
  try:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(dev, True)
    print(dev, "SET MEMORY GROWTH")
  except:
    print("Device config error")
    sys.exit(1)
```

however now I got a similar warning:

```
2020-04-07 01:39:57.857284: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:801] failed to allocate 2.70G (2897281024 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory

2020-04-07 01:39:58.035192: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:309] Garbage collection: deallocate free memory regions (i.e., allocations) so that we can re-allocate a larger region to avoid OOM due to memory fragmentation. If you see this message frequently, you are running near the threshold of the available device memory and re-allocation may incur great performance overhead. You may try smaller batch sizes to observe the performance impact. Set TF_ENABLE_GPU_GARBAGE_COLLECTION=false if you'd like to disable this feature.
```

both printed several times.

After this I get:

```
2020-04-07 01:41:59.069302: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Cancelled: Operation was cancelled
```

I read that they are not related, but it's not clear to me what may cause this second warning.

In the end, this appeared:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
```

(I think they're caused by three different issues, I decided to post all in a single question to not spam around, but if this is a problem I can split in different threads.)

I used `ImageDataGenerator` to generate datasets:

```
train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255., rotation_range=10., horizontal_flip=True) # Generator for our training data
validation_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255.) # Generator for our validation data

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                        directory=train_dir,
                                                        shuffle=True,
                                                        target_size=(IMG_H, IMG_W),
                                                        class_mode='sparse')

validation_data_gen = validation_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                          directory=validation_dir,
                                                          shuffle=True,
                                                          target_size=(IMG_H, IMG_W),
                                                          class_mode='sparse')
```

If some other code is needed I will add.

Thanks.

**EDIT1:**

for the warning:

```
2020-04-07 01:41:59.069302: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Cancelled: Operation was cancelled
```

I tried to set `workers=1` in `fit()` and it disappear but I don't still know the cause and the consequences of this warning.

Comment: Same god***n problem here.  I woud never touch tensorflow if I didn't have to but would go for pytorch.

Answer (score 0):

This Error Is due to GPU is already occupied due to your previous Run of the program. Now when you try to re-run there is no memory available to occupy model again.

Do the Following -

---

1. Open terminal & type ***nivida-smi***
2. Find the process ID (PID) occupying your GPU
3. Kill the process (PID) occupying the gpu using ***kill -9 PID***

> Note - You can also kill process using ***top***

Comment: I don't think so, because I get this warnings also at first start

Comment: ResNet-50 training on high-performance GPU needs over 7.5 GB of DRAM, And your GPU is 6GB, Try using Sequential model with 2-3 Layer Network and find out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has something to do with TensorFlow version 2.1

Try upgrading it to 2.2 or above, that may solve the issue